# What prevents a Navigation between two XAML-pages?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013, c++-cx

I am experiencing a very strange bug in my c++/cx XAML app:
I have a back-button that checks if the progress you made is saved and (in case it isn't) pops up a flyout that lets you save or leave without saving. This is done with `this->frame->goBack()` in both cases, however:

*When the progress **was** saved, the app halts at a* `__debugbreak()` *however, when* `goBack()` *is called by the button on the flyout, everything works out fine. Why could that possibly be the case?*

## Things that might help you:

*The app is based on the "Blank App" template, the pages itself are based on the "Basic Page" template provided by Visual Studio 2013*

The Controls in `BoardPage.xaml` are defined as follows:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="backButton" Icon="Back" Height="95"
    Click="backButton_Clicked">
    <AppBarButton.Resources>
        <Flyout x:Key="WarningFlyoutBase">
            <Grid Height="150" Width="200">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Unsaved progress, what do you want to do?"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    FontSize="14" Margin="4,10" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="WarningSaveButton"
                    Content="Save now." 
                    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="WarningSaveButton_Clicked"/>
                <Button x:Name="WarningLeaveButton"
                    Content="Leave without saving." 
                    Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Click="WarningLeaveButton_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
    </AppBarButton.Resources>
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="WarningFlyoutBase"/>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

so these three controls (`backButton`, `WarningSaveButton` and `WarningLeaveButton`) all have their respective Clicked event handlers, though only two of them are relevant right now:

**backButton:**

```
void Tackle::BoardPage::backButton_Clicked(Platform::Object^ sender,
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (saved && Frame->CanGoBack) /* saved is a bool */
        this->Frame->GoBack();
    else
        backButton->Flyout->ShowAt((FrameworkElement^)sender);
}
```

Note: I also tried replacing `GoBack()` with `Navigate(TypeName(CreateGamePage::typeid))`, but that didn't help.

**WarningLeaveButton:**

```
void Tackle::BoardPage::WarningLeaveButton_Clicked(Platform::Object^ sender, 
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (Frame->CanGoBack)
        this->Frame->GoBack();
}
```

### other strange stuff:

I tried to examine the reasons for this crash/debugbreak for quite some time, and found the following:

- the page in question is navigated to with `this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(BoardPage::typeid), ref new CGameSession(job));`. leaving out the second argument fixes the crash magically.
- When the breakpoint is triggered in `App.g.hpp`, opening a watch on the value `errorMessage` reveales:

  > "Placement target needs to be in visual tree."

  *How come the Flyout is in the visual tree, but the Button it's been attached to isn't?*
- The target page *is* in fact constructed, but the `NavigationHelper->OnNavigatedTo(e)` method fails in the last line `LoadState(this, ref new LoadStateEventArgs(e->Parameter, safe_cast<IMap<String^, Object^>^>(frameState->Lookup(_pageKey))));`, wich seems paritularly odd, because `LoadState()` gets called easily and only contains two `(void)` typecasts. (I have not modified a single one of these methods.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem here lies within the way flyouts and event handlers work with XAML-Controls, there are 2 mayor points that cause my code to crash:

1. Flyouts are *always* shown when the button they're attached to is clicked or tapped.
2. Event Handlers seem to be executed *before* the flyout gets shown.

#### What follows from this?

Well, when the `backButton` is pressed, `backButton_Clicked` gets triggered first.
When the game is not saved, the flyout opens and you can go back without a Problem.
But if the game *was*  saved previously, the event handler immediately calls `this->Frame->GoBack()`, wich does exactly what it should, constructs the previous page, loads its state and draws it.
**BUT** after that, it tries to open the flyout, and this is the problem here: The flyout doesn't exist anymore, hence the strange error Message.

I am kind of embarassed it took me this long to figure it out, but maybe someone will find this useful in the future, so I'm going to leave this question here.

#### Workaround:

The workaround I'm using for this now  is to move the FlyoutBase to the `<Page.Resources>` and attach it to a button with a size of 0x0 px. Triggering the flyout then done like so: `Flyout::ShowAttachedFlyout(InvisibleButton);`